# Express Partial Sum of a Geometric Series Without $r$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

For arithmetic series, one has the formula
$$
S_n = \frac{n}{2} \left(a_1 + a_n \right) \tag{1}
$$
where $S_n$ is the sum of the first $n$ terms of the arithmetic sequence $(a_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$.

For geometric series, one has
$$
S_n = a_1 \left(\frac{r^n - 1}{r - 1}\right) \tag{2}
$$
where, again, $S_n$ is the sum of the first $n$ terms of the geometric sequence $(a_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $a_2 = ra_1$.

Unlike equation (1), equation (2) depends explicitly on the common ratio $r$. Is there a way to express $S_n$ only in terms of $n$, $a_1$, and $a_n$? So far the best I've been able to do is to write
$$
S_n = \frac{ra_n - a_1}{r - 1} \tag{3}
$$
which is fairly obvious and doesn't completely eliminate $r$. I could see it not being possible in general since two terms do not uniquely determine a geometric sequence. For example, the geometric sequence with $a_1 = 1$ and $a_3 = 1$ could be $1,1,1,\ldots$ or $1,-1,1,\ldots$, which have different values for $S_3$. But perhaps there is some equation for $S_n$ depending on $n$, $a_1$, and $a_n$ which breaks into cases depending on, say, the sign of $r$? Or maybe there is a single formula if we assume the $a_k$ are positive?

Comment: Since $a_n=a_0r^n$, you have $$r=\left(\frac{a_n}{a_0}\right)^{1/n}\;,$$ and you can substitute that for every occurrence of $r$ in the usual formula.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I'll check to see if it simplifies down to anything particularly nice.